# Facebook credit Integration errors

Tags: php, facebook

I have created a facebook application for integrating facebook credits.It is working fine but i have some doubts regarding on that
In call back payment get items function i have used this code for assigning order information

```
 if ($func == 'payments_get_items') {
// remove escape characters  
$order_info = stripcslashes($payload['order_info']);
 if (is_string($order_info)) {  
$item = json_decode($order_info, true);
$item['item_id'] = intval($item['GreeID']);
}
}
```

I want to get the `item_id` in 'payments_status_update update function.I have used `$payload['order_details']` method .I am getting all the values in a json format.But when i use json_decode the purchase is not working properly.Is their any other method to get the `item_id` inside `payments_status_update function`

```
if ($func == 'payments_status_update')
{
  $payload['order_details']
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$order_info = json_decode(preg_replace('/:(\d+)/', ':"${1}"',stripcslashes($payload['order_details'])),true);
```